# Would Google My Business allow these two businesses to share the same address?

Tags: google, google-my-business

I have a question about Google's preferences for businesses that share a location.

A roofing company and a construction company are run out of the same building. They're both owned by the same person, but have different staff, perform different services, and have unique phone numbers and websites.

A few questions come up with this arrangement:
1. Can these two businesses share the same address on Google My Business?

2. Will Google remove or merge them if the address is changed to reflect that they share the same office? I've read that Google may consider roofing a service of the construction company, even though they are unique businesses.
3. If they can share the same address, are there any other requirements for this arrangement? I've read that businesses at the same address require permanent signage for each business, suite numbers, and individual entrances for each business.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from experience. We had two listings for the same Business, by different names(one with an extra word) on Google My Business(GMB). 
The same address.
The same contact details.
The same website.

e.g:

```
XYZ IT Services.

Address... Contact... Website...
```

And

```
XYZ IT Consultancy and Services.

Address... Contact... Website...
```

(It was due to miscommunication between our team members, but let's not get into that)

And it lasted for quite a while. Only after Multiple tries to de-list the duplicate listing, and contacting Google Support many times was that problem rectified.

Yours seem to be a far less difficult problem. As long as both the businesses are verified by Google(Through their offline Verification Process), it would be fine to list two different companies with the same details.